# How to hide "null" in the input field Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

When a value of null comes to the JSON, it appears in the input field. How can I hide it and not display it? And to show only the name in the meaning?

[image: Screenshot of fields showing null]

```html
<div>
    <input type="hidden" 
        name="roleUserHidden-{{roleIndex}}" 
        #roleUser="ngModel" 
        [ngModel]="role.UserId === 'null' ? '' : role.UserId " />
    <input [disabled]="!permissions.canEdit" 
        class="form-control" 
        auto-complete 
        [ngModel]="role === 'null' ? '' : role" [source]="usersForAllocationSource.bind(this)" 
        list-formatter="Name" 
        name="roleUserAuto-{{roleIndex}}" 
        #roleUserVisible="ngModel" 
        (valueChanged)="usersForAllocationSelected(role, $event, roleUser)" 
        display-property-name="UserName" 
        [accept-user-input]="false" 
        (ngModelChange)="onRoleUserChange($event, role)" 
        [min-chars]="2">
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094103/495157 - uses a directive

Comment: It's not supposed to show 'null' unless it's a string.

Comment: check for null in ts and assign to the input ngModel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution :

```
<input name='name' [ngModel]="obj?.val">
```

Another way :

```
<input name='name' [ngModel]="obj.val ? obj.val  : '' ">
```

Here is the link to [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9TicBdIblfpPFtTs1aDd?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the entire input element you can do `*ngIf="value"` value being whatever is null...

if you want the value to be an empty string you can do `[value]="value === 'null' ? '' : value"`