# To display empty value in the input field if the property value is null

Tags: angular, typescript

My JSON looks like this:

```
[
 {
   "firstName": "tom",
   "lastName": "null",
   "phone": "null",
   "status": "Active",
 },
 {
   "firstName": "Bob",
   "lastName": "null",
   "phone": "null",
   "status": "Inactive",
 }
]
```

I am displaying the 2nd property(i,e lastName) of the `JSON` object like this:

```
  <div class="form-group" >
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="customer.lastName">
  </div>
```

Since its value is `null` it displays as `null` , Here i need to write condition like this:

> If the properties(lastName,phone... ) value is `null` in the input it should not display anything,but input should to visible to the user.

Comment: Its value is not `null`. Its value is the string `"null"`. Fix your JSON. Once fixed, everything will work fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vc9nhd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: While creating the customer object,Intentionally we store  `lastName`(type:string) as `null`.

Comment: I am looking for this **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45476141/how-to-hide-null-in-the-input-field-angular-2**

Comment: you design is severely broken. You're using a special string `"null"` (i.e. the 4 letters n, ul, l, l), instead of the literal null, which means "the absence of a value. Fix that. You won't be able to do anything clean and correct using that design. And what if someone's last name is actually "null"?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance,I will fix  it.I will use literal null instead of  special string "null", Even for the literal how can i write the condition?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special if you correctly use null. See my first comment.

Answer (score 2):

> You can achieve this just using **Conditional (Ternary) Operator** in your ng model like
>   below.

```
<div class="form-group" >
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="customer.lastName === 'null' ? '' : customer.lastName">
  </div>
```

Comment: No, that wouldn't be valid. Angular needs to **update** the value of the expression, and this expression is not writeable.

Comment: @JBNizet There is no need of updating angular. Ng Model is accepting the condition's from Angular 2. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144230/conditional-ngmodel-in-angular2 for your reference.

Comment: See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7bti4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html.