# using [(ngModel)] with nullable types from database

Tags: angular

My application has data fields that are nullable. For example two date fields PublishOn & ExpiresOn. Both of them can be null or have a valid date.

At the client end, I have an object with matching fields that gets populated with the data coming from web APIs. However when I am binding data as below

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="Title" [(ngModel)] = "entity.PublishOn">
```

it works fine when PublishOn property has a value. When it's null it fails. I know I can transform any null values to an empty string or something after I get the data, but was wondering why Angular is not flexible in this case? I mean if there is a value it binds and if its empty/null it just leaves as it is.

What is the Angular way to handle this scenario?

**Update - 1**

I followed ValueAccessor samples in ;
[here](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Creating-A-Directive-in-Angular-4) and [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-default-value-accessor-issue?file=app%2Fdirective.ts)

However everytime it runs, gives me an exception "More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute" I have a simple requirement. That is before the binding value to control it should check for null. If it's null should return an empty string!

Comment: Angular should be fine handling this. What is the error message you get? Are you sure that PublishOn is null? Isn't it maybe entity itself which is null in the first place?

Comment: What is your expectation ? it is not clear from the question...

Comment: Exception is simple. it says "TypeError: _co.form.publishOn is undefined" and gives  a large stack trace. So. it is only the PublishOn date property that is undefined. Reason is user have not decided a publishOn date when creating the record. It is a valid use case and the db stores a null. if the db has a date, it gets converted to a momentjs object at client. In that case angular binds it properly.

Comment: What I expect angular to do in this case is not to complain about null. Because in this case it's valid to have a null. Since it throws an error, it breaks my other functionality in the data entry popup.

Comment: see this if that can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38527535/angular-2-set-null-as-empty-string-value-for-input-field

Comment: well, i got to learn a bit more about valueaccessors, but still couldn't get it done. I have updated my question above with what I found.

Comment: Are you sure that `entity` itself is not null or undefined? If you put `[ngModel]="entity?.PublishOn"` (one way binding, just to see the value), does it fail? I also note that the error mentions `form.publishOn`, but your property is `entity.PublishOn`. What is `form.publishOn`?

Comment: @user2058413 All you need to do is put (?) on `entity?.PublishOn` should be fine i am guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `entity` is a defined class setting  `entity.publishOn`  to a default value of `''` is a simple thing.

If there is a chance that `entity` itself is `null` then you might be better off exposing the same via a variable in controller with get and set methods something like

```
 private _entity:Entity; // this is the declaration of the variable 
    ...
    ...
    constructor(){
       this._entity = new Entity();
    }
    ...
    ...
    get entity():Entity{
      return this._entity;
    }
    set entity(value:Entity):void{
      if(value){
    this._entity =value;
      }else{
       this._entity = new Entity() // cases when we want to reset the value
    }
   }
```

Comment: what if I deal with numbers. I can't set it to `' '`then. I could set it to 0 but I would rather have an empty input field. setting it to `null` would resolve in an error

Comment: @Jonas there are a lot of what if's here, your mileage varies with what you have in the html / render block, the logic defined above is only to provide a sane non null ```_entity``` object so that ```_entity.something``` will not blow up with a null exception. Generally passing null as a value requires the consumer of your function to handle null

Answer (score 5):

If you are restricted with the angular version you are using then you can handle the scenario with the use of ngIf statement.

```
<ng-template [ngIf]= "ngModel" >
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Title" [(ngModel)] = "entity.PublishOn">
</ng-template>

 <ng-template [ngIf]= "!ngModel" >
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Title" >
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works fine now with Angular 6. If the variable property is not defined, it will automatically bind the entered value by creating the property.

Till you upgrade to Angular 6, you may use like:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="Title" [(ngModel)]"entity?.PublishOn">
```

Comment: Are you saying in Angular 5; the ?. operator works? Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: yes, by this you can even add a new variable in the list's object dynamically if it doesn't exist.

Comment: How to overcome from this situation if  `[(ngModel)]"entity?.PublishOn.id"` check `id` to null bcoz `[(ngModel)]"entity.PublishOn?.id"` not work..?

Comment: ... And what happens when [(ngModel)]="myNumber"... when myNumber is null, It would be nice to leave the entry empty